# ANN regression NaN loss values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm trying to train an ANN to perform regression. The dataset consists of ~10k data points for 7 parameters. I'm using [this basic regression example from Tensorflow.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression#full_model)

However, during training, the loss values return NaN values from the very first epoch to the last. I've tried different regularization techniques (Normalization, dropout, L1/L2 weight regularization) without any success.

Any suggestions on what could be the source of this, and how to solve?

Below are some useful code-snippets and images:

**Model**

```
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
  model = keras.Sequential([
      norm,
      layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)),
      layers.Dense(1)
  ])
  model.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(6,)))
  model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001))
  return model

dnn_model = build_and_compile_model(normalizer)
dnn_model.summary()
```

**Training**

```
%%time
history = dnn_model.fit(
    train_features, train_labels,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=0, epochs=100)

hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
print(hist.head())
print(hist.tail())

# PRINT:
loss  val_loss  epoch
0   NaN       NaN      0
1   NaN       NaN      1
2   NaN       NaN      2
3   NaN       NaN      3
4   NaN       NaN      4
    loss  val_loss  epoch
95   NaN       NaN     95
96   NaN       NaN     96
97   NaN       NaN     97
98   NaN       NaN     98
99   NaN       NaN     99
Wall time: 26.1 s
```

**Data inspection**

Last row is output parameter.

[image]

Comment: you got inf (np.inf) values in your dataset?

Comment: Check if youd on't have any `NaN` values in your dataframe

Comment: NaN means your loss has become infinite. Try to reduce your learning rate (e.g. 0.000001 or even zero) so you can see if your model learns in a bad way or the problem is something else. And  as a suggestion I say remove `norm` layer and regularizers and try simplest version of your network until it works

Comment: @Yefet I tried replacing all inf values with NaN values using `dataset.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` with no sucess. However, it works when removing all NaN values ass well with `dataset.dropna(inplace=True)`. This reduces the dataset significantly though. Does NaN values really affect the training this way?

Comment: @BDouchet See comment above. It works when removing all NaN values, but it significantly reduces the dataset from 10k to 3k data points resulting in bad training. I guess i have to experiment with training parameters to get it to work!

Comment: @fendrbud try maybe to complete your missing values with [linear interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have added a Dropout layer after the Dense(1) layer.
This makes dropout the top layer of your model. Remove it and it should work

Comment: I've tried many different configurations of the model with no success. With and without dropout, different number of neurons in the hidden layer, etc.